# Is it possible to check if shared pointer returns a nullptr in native unit test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012 native unit test, the code can't be compiled when using shared pointer.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "ParameterTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace MyParameter;

namespace MyParameterTests
{       
    TEST_CLASS(MyParameterTests)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(CheckParametersWithPathReturnsNotNull)
        {
            //Arrange
            Parameter parameter = Parameter();

            //Act
            std::shared_ptr<std::string> actual = parameter.CheckParameters("C:\\Parameter.db");

            //Assert
            Assert::IsNotNull(actual, L"Should not return null", LINE_INFO());

        }

    };
}
```

Compiler eror:

> 2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyParameterTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   2>  stdafx.cpp
>   2>  ParameterTestTests.cpp
>   2>c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\myparametertests\parametertests.cpp(26): error C2784: 'void Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::IsNotNull(const T *,const wchar_t *,const Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::__LineInfo *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const T *' from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
>   2>          with
>   2>          [
>   2>              _Ty=std::string
>   2>          ]
>   2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h(259) : see declaration of 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::IsNotNull'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should replace

```
Assert::IsNotNull(actual, L"Should not return null", LINE_INFO());
```

with

```
Assert::IsNotNull(actual.get(), L"Should not return null", LINE_INFO());
```

Indeed, the assertion wants a pointer to check if it's null, but a smart-pointer *isn't a pointer* strictly speaking (it's an object that manages a pointer).